# How to remove text | xslt

Tags: xslt

Output data:

```
<sku>SKU 11077</sku>
```

XSLT

```
        <xsl:element name="sku">
                V31L-<xsl:value-of select="sku"/>
            </xsl:element>
```

I try to remove `SKU` and `SPACE`  to get result:

```
<sku>V31L-11077</sku>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xslt has the substring-after function, that you can use like this:

```
<xsl:element name="sku">
  <xsl:text>V31L-</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(sku,'SKU ')"/>
</xsl:element>
```